# XMPP (XMPPHP) session won't start

Tags: php, xmpp, ejabberd, xmpphp

Fellows I'm working in a new server and, at first, it looks all good. The eJabberd webadmin runs OK and I was able to even create an user by that interface.

The situation is, the same application that usually ran on my previous server freezes at the waiting for the session to start, the code:

```
$this->lnk->processUntil('session_start');
```

The `$this->lnk->connect();` works fine but it seems that the session can't be set. Any suggestions for where or what I should go take a look first?

ACKs:

- The XMPP application has been set the same way than was in the older server.

Here is the whole code:

```
$this->lnk = new XMPPHP_XMPP($this->config['host'], 
                             $this->config['port'], 
                             $this->config['username'], 
                             $this->config['password'], 
                             $this->config['service'], 
                             $this->config['domain'], 
                             $printlog = false, 
                             $loglevel = XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);

$this->lnk->useEncryption(true);

$this->lnk->connect();

$this->lnk->processUntil('session_start');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by `$this->lnk->useEncryption(true);`. Since my new server hadn't proper SSL/TLS settings, this line caused the freezing of the code.
Possible solvings are disabling encryption and adjusting you SSL/TLS credentials.